# After upgrading Xcode 6, the snapshots are lost

Tags: xcode, upgrade, snapshot

I've lost the all snapshots I created, and the current project is somehow buggy and cannot function properly  since I've tried to add some new features and failed.

Can anyone tell me how can I go back to my functioning version now that the snapshots are lost? Or can I retrieve one iTunesconnect version that i can edit?

Thank you very much!!!

Answer (score 0):

Xcode 5 stored Snapshots in `~/Library/Application Support/Developer/Shared/Xcode`. Xcode 6 stores them in `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/Snapshots`.

You could:

1. Try moving them from the old location to the new location and see if Xcode 6 will recognize them
2. Open Xcode 5 and revert your project there (you can download it from the Dev Center if you deleted it during install, or it might still be in your trash)

The installer shouldn't delete the snapshot files.

Also, for the future, you should use Git or another source control software and not rely on snapshots for this.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But I still cannot find the snapshots in the directory you mentioned. Is there any other way to recover my project? Thank you very much.